# Kruskals Algorithm explained

Tags: algorithm

So I'm currently having a little play with some algorithms and have come across the Kruskals algorithm.

Understand the concept, understand how to do the actual process. But do not understand the algorithm.

Here is the algorithm:

[image]

From what I can figure out, |V| is all the vertices?

What is E'?
I have no idea why this algorithm is confusing me so much, I've picked up other ones with absolute ease

Comment: So what does E' := 0/ mean? Yeah I do I've done examples @dingalapadum

Comment: E' are the edges appearing in the spanning tree. You know what the algo actually tries to achieve? (Sorry, edited. I didn't read your question carefully enough - just saw the ' in E')

Comment: Okay what I thought was E' is an empty set, and and E is all the edges. It then loops until E' < n -1 and until all the edges have been removed from E. It then deletes the smallest edge and checks to see if it makes a cycle in E', if it does it ignores it, if it doesn't it puts it in. Then it does a last check

Comment: yes. you are correct. that is what is happening. now, if in the end, after the whole loop |E'| < n-1, then the graph is not connected (a tree always has n-1 edges), hence there is no spanning tree. Now if |E'|==n-1, then E' is the set of edges of your spanning tree.

Comment: look it up on wikipedia. it's really well explained: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kruskal's algorithm adds edges to the MST in order of weight, unless they would introduce a cycle (this detection is typically done using *union-find*). The code starts by initialising some values:

```
n := |V|  // the number of vertices
E' := ∅   // the edges in our MST; it starts as the empty set
Cands = E // the edges still under consideration for adding to the MST, starts as all edges
```

The loop condition is:

```
while |E'| < n - 1 and Cands != ∅ do
```

That is, we continue as long as we have selected fewer than `n - 1` edges (because we know this is the number of edges contained in any spanning tree: if we have found them, we're done) and the set of edges we haven't considered yet is not empty.

Lines (1) and (2) find the minimum weight edge in `Cands`, removing it from the set. A suitable structure for `Cands` would be a min-heap, in which case this is just a pop-operation.

Lines (3) and (4) determine whether the edge we retrieved from `Cands` in (1) would introduce a cycle in `E'` if added. If it doesn't, we know this edge is in the MST, otherwise it's not.

The last line just checks to see whether we actually found a tree. It's possible the loop terminates without finding `n - 1` edges, for instance when the graph is not one connected component.